# Issue performing remote ls in a bash while loop

Tags: bash, ssh

I need to perform the following in a single BASH one-liner. To preferace, I have four systems; lets call them A, B, C, and D.

System A can SSH to System B and System C.

System B can SSH to System D.

From System A the following command is run:

`ssh systemB "cd folder && (while true; do val1=\$(ssh systemD 'ls directory' | wc -l); val2=$(ssh systemC 'ls directory' | wc -l); echo "\$val1  \$val2"; if (( val1 == 0 && val2 == 0 )); then echo "Done"; break; fi; sleep 5; done;)"`

It seems to get the correct file counts the first time the loop runs. When the file counts in both directories change after the loop has started, the values of `val1` and `val2` seems to stay constant.

Comment: "_perform the following in a single BASH one-liner_" - for readability consider writing multiple lines and putting them in a script. Or write multiple lines, again for readability, and then crunch them to a single line once the code is working

Answer (score 2):

If `systemB` cannot `ssh` to `systemC`, you cannot have your loop there. It will have to be driven from `systemA`:

```
until
  val1=$(ssh -J systemB systemD "ls -q directory | wc -l")
  val2=$(ssh systemC "ls -q directory | wc -l")
  echo "$val1  $val2"
  [ "$val1" -eq 0 ] && [ "$val2" -eq 0 ]
do
  sleep 5
done
echo Done
```

Also:

- adding `-q` to `ls` without which you'd also count the newlines in file names.  Not really a problem here as long as it's only about checking that the number is non-zero.
- doing the counting (`wc -l`) on the remote to avoid transferring the whole file list.
- make it clearer what the exit condition is.
- using `-J systemB` to use `systemB` as a *jump* host. Note that authentication to `systemC` is still done using the `systemA` credentials (ssh agent or key). To use `systemB`'s, do: `ssh systemB 'ssh systemD "ls -q directory | wc -l"'`.

Instead of counting the files, you could use `ls | grep -q '^'` which stops at the first match, and also avoid sshing to systemC if there were files on systemD:

```
while
  ssh -J systemB systemD "ls -U directory | grep -q \^" ||
    ssh systemC "ls -U directory | grep -q \^"
do
  sleep 5
done
echo Done
```

(assuming GNU `ls` for its `-U` option to skip sorting, which means `ls` can start outputting file names as it reads them from the directory)

Using ssh control sockets would also avoid doing expensive ssh connection, authentication at each run.

Comment: The only thing not working for this is that this is performing an SSH to SystemC, which I had mentioned only SystemA has access to.

Comment: @dlambros, sorry I had missed that part of your requirement. I suppose that's why you left that `$` unescaped, but that can't work that way. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you write the code like below, instead of a big one-liner, you'd see immediately what is wrong.

```
ssh systemB "cd folder &&
            (while true; do
                val1=\$(ssh systemD 'ls directory' | wc -l); 
                val2=$(ssh systemC 'ls directory' | wc -l); 
                echo "\$val1  \$val2"; 
                if (( val1 == 0 && val2 == 0 )); then 
                    echo "Done"; 
                    break; 
               fi; 
               sleep 5; 
            done;)"
```

You're missing a `\` before the `$` in the line of `val2`. Therefore, `val2` is created at the moment that `ssh systemB` is done, and not as part of the loop.

So if, when you start this command, `$(ssh systemC 'ls directory' | wc -l)` is 10, the loop will be

```
ssh systemB "cd folder &&
            (while true; do
                val1=\$(ssh systemD 'ls directory' | wc -l); 
                val2=10; 
                echo "\$val1  \$val2"; 
                if (( val1 == 0 && val2 == 0 )); then 
                    echo "Done"; 
                    break; 
               fi; 
               sleep 5; 
            done;)"
```

Comment: This is not missing a `\ ` before the `$` in the line of `val2`. The escape character causes the command on the line of val1 to be executed in the shell of systemB. The regular `$` sign causes the command to be executed in the shell of systemA.

Comment: Yes, the `val2` is set to the value `$(ssh systemC 'ls directory' | wc -l)` at the moment that the arguments for `ssh systemB` are evaluated. That means once, and not as part of the loop.